# I need .htaccess redirection to video.domain.com/date/id

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I need to redirect;

```
http://video.domain.com/date/videoid
```

to

```
http://www.domain.com/video/video.php?date=$date&videoid=$id
```

Thanks a lot...

Comment: I've been trying til last night. Lots of htaccess code i've dealed with no chance..

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^video\.domain\.com\([^\.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ video/video.php?test=$1 [L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^video\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ video/video.php?date=$1&videoid=$2 [L]
```

Do note that the above would work if both `domain.com` and `video.domain.com` are hosted on the same server.

Comment: I am redirecting everythin to video/video.php with the code above but I need to redirect;

video.domain.com/category to www.domain.com/video/category.php how to hack the code?